# How to set specific location as an object's default (0,0,0)

Tags: transforms

So, my specific problem is the following:
I have a scene setup with multiple cameras in it.
When I add a new object like a cube, I would like it to have the camera's position as it's default location (0,0,0). Or in other words, I'd like to have the location coordinates of the object being relative to the camera position.
I can instantiate the object at the camera position using the 3D cursor, but that still gives me the world coordinates as the object's location.
I thought that "apply" does set the transformations to 0,0,0 at the current position, but turns out it doesn't.

I couldn't find a way to do it, but I might just not be searching with the right key words.
So any help on how to achieve this is much appreciated.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to achieve, but if I understand it correctly, you want the camera to be the origin of an object? And the position of the object should be relative to the cameras position? If that is the case, use an empty at the cameras position, set it as a parent to the camera and all the corresponding objects. I'm not at my computer at the moment, so I can't try but it probably works if you set the camera as parent as well. All the best Marco

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for! :D
Works with the camera as the parent as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>, select  `cursor to the world origin`. If you now add a cube, it will be placed in the world origin.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that wasn't what I was looking for. But I got the answer I needed (see above). Still, appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> *Apply Location*, resetting the object’s origin to be the location of the 3d cursor. Then a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> *Apply Rotation* will set the object’s default rotation to the current rotation.